# Link Google Earth with QGis

Tags: qgis, coordinates, google-earth, google-earth-pro

I was wondering if it was possible to link Google Earth files (KML, KMZ) to a QGIS project. The main idea would be that if you'd add a point with coordinates in Google Earth, this point would be added to your QGis project or vice versa.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than linking the two together, use the OpenLayers plugin which allows you to view Google satellite imagery in QGIS.

[image: OpenLayers plugin]

You can then edit and save your data in QGIS as a KML (right click save as on your layer) and import into Google Earth if required for fly through's / oblique screenshots etc.